# Is there a way to set the ZIndex of different ItemsControl within the same canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, z-index, itemscontrol

I'm trying to set the ZIndex of different ItemsControls within a canvas and initially I did this which worked fine. Each of the following Collections was organised as expected.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllPoints.PointsObjects}" Panel.ZIndex={Binding ZIndex}>

 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllTracks.TrackObjects}" Panel.ZIndex={Binding ZIndex}>
```

However I need to be able to change the ZIndexes of each item within each ItemsControl individually. So I moved the ZIndex Binding to each individual object and tried to set the ZIndex using ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle. But the collections did not appear in the order as expected.

```
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllPoints.PointsObjects}">

                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <!--Resource dictionary template-->
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                
                </ItemsControl>


                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllTracks.TrackObjects}">

                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <!--Resource dictionary template-->
                    </ItemsControl.Resources>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Would I need to create just one ItemsControl or is it possible to link different ItemsControl's ZIndexes by use ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: ZIndex is significant only for the children of a single Panel. You need to use a single ItemsControl and probably put PointObjects and TrackObjects into a CompositeCollection.

Comment: ZIndex is an attachable property from the panel.
It is not global in nature, but is processed by only one panel in which the element is located.
In your case, the ZIndex of the ItemsControl items affects their order in the ItemsPanel.
And the ZIndex of the ItemsPanel themselves affects the order of the ItemsPanel among themselves.
If an ItemsPanel has a lower index than another, then all of its items will be lower than the other's items, regardless of the item index.

Comment: If you need a global shuffling of elements among themselves, then all of them must be combined into one collection so that they all appear in one panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Clemens answer to my post this is the solution to my question. Within the Windows.Resources.

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Points" Source="{Binding AllPoints.PointsObjects}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Tracks" Source="{Binding AllTracks.TrackObjects}"/>
     

        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CombinedCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Points}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tracks}}" />

        </CompositeCollection>
            
    </Window.Resources>
```

And within the Canvas.

```
<Canvas>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinedCollection}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```